# have pdb file still cant debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to debug my dll and I have the pdb file next to the dll and I still can't step into the method. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the assembly loaded in your application is not the version that is loaded in Visual Studio.

If both projects are in the same solution, ensure you are adding a reference by using a Project Reference rather than browsing to the /bin folder.  In cases like this, you may browse to the /bin/release version, then set the Build to Debug, causing the problem you are experiencing.

If projects are in two different solutions, ensure the solution you wish to debug is cleaned and rebuilt, and then re-add the reference to the fresh assembly in the running project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the PDB is the latest build. Also make sure the PDB is in the same folder as the EXE you are running.

Answer (score 0):

As Travyguy9 mentioned make sure that you have rebuilded whole solution. Also from time to time I also can't debug and then I have to close VS and open it again.